# Using "Since" with past simple

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Which is more accurate

"This was the context of multiple questions I asked since I started working here."

Or

"This was the context of multiple questions I have asked since I started working here."

I've been taught at school to *always* use the present perfect with "since", but the first sentence makes more sense to me. Thoughts?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with either version.

Answer (score 1):

The most usual would be to match the "questions I have asked" with the period "since I started working here".  As the working is continuing, so might be the asking.

- "This was the context of multiple question**s** I **have asked** since I started working here."

However there's nothing wrong with the alternative.

If the period is finished:

- Things he **did** when he was a child.  (of anyone, alive or dead, who is no longer a child)
- Things Mozart **did** during his lifetime.  (Person no longer living)

But

- Things my brother **has done** during his lifetime.  (Person still living)

Comment: What if I'm no longer asking question, or generally not doing the action that precedes "Since"? Do I use the past simple then?

Comment: To my mostly UK ears they sound almost identical.

Answer (score -1):

I would opt unhesitatingly for the present perfect in nearly all sentences starting with since (when it is not used to mean **for this reason**).

Its usage nearly always covers a period from a point in the past up to the present, which is exactly what the present perfect signifies.

But your examples raise a question. If something has provoked questions since you started working there, the obvious constructions are either:

> This **has been** the context of multiple questions I **have asked** since I started working here.
>   or
>   This **is** the context of multiple questions I **have asked** since I started working here.

If by **was the context** you mean that it is no longer the context, you might say:

> This was the context of multiple questions I asked after I started working here.

This would indicate that it is no longer the context and the issue no longer bothers you.

I would add that the BBC appears to adopted a policy of using the past tense in its news bulletins in contexts where the present perfect is called for - and it never fails to jar on my ears.